# pandas dataframe groupby summation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions, dataframe

input:

```
       Date letters numbers mixed         new
0  1/2/2014       a       6    z1  1/2/2014 a
1  1/2/2014       a       3    z1  1/2/2014 a
2  1/3/2014       c       1    x3  1/3/2014 c
```

I want to groupby `new` and sum `numbers` so that the output is:

```
       Date letters numbers mixed         new
0  1/2/2014       a       9    z1  1/2/2014 a
1  1/3/2014       c       1    x3  1/3/2014 c
```

I've looked through here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
a=[['Date', 'letters', 'numbers', 'mixed'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', '6', 'z1'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1'], ['1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3']]
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:],columns=a[0])
f=[]
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    f.append(df['Date'][i] + ' ' + df['letters'][i])
df['new']=f
```

Also, any tricks that will concatenate `date` and `letters` without looping thru would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your `numbers` column to `int`

```
import pandas as pd
a=[['Date', 'letters', 'numbers', 'mixed'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', '6', 'z1'], ['1/2/2014', 'a', '3', 'z1'], ['1/3/2014', 'c', '1', 'x3']]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a[1:],columns=a[0])
df['new'] = df.Date + " " + df.letters
df.numbers = df.numbers.astype(int)

print df

       Date letters  numbers mixed         new
0  1/2/2014       a        6    z1  1/2/2014 a
1  1/2/2014       a        3    z1  1/2/2014 a
2  1/3/2014       c        1    x3  1/3/2014 c
```

You can get the dataframe you want to merge with:

```
df_to_merge = df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['numbers'])]].drop_duplicates()
```

Then you can do your `groupby`

```
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('new').numbers.sum()).reset_index()
```

To get the result you posted `merge`

```
df_result = df_to_merge.merge(df_grouped)
print df_result

       Date letters mixed         new  numbers
0  1/2/2014       a    z1  1/2/2014 a        9
1  1/3/2014       c    x3  1/3/2014 c        1
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Could you please modify your answer for a general solution? ie. what if I had 50 columns instead of the 4 columns in the example. That would much appreciated.

Comment: btw, i tried your code and still getting the original input back

Comment: You'll have to post your output because I get exactly your desired result.  I'll update to make more general.  Also...do you really need the column "new" or are you just using it to group by?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I do need the column 'new', it will be part of the dataset going forward.

Comment: One last question on your code. What if 'numbers' had a column name such as 'big numbers'. for the `df_grouped` statement, the `.numbers` would need to be changed. `.big numbers` does obviously does not work.

Comment: @jason_cant_code you can reference the column with `df['big numbers']` the pandas documentation and intro has all of this syntax info in it